# Java interfaces for IBM ILOG

Tags: java, ilog

I have installed the IBM ILOG v12.2 for Linux on a server whose OS is Red Hat Linux. I programmed the Java interfaces, and when I run it on the server, the following errors show:

```
Native code library failed to load: ensure the appropriate library (opl<VERSION>.dll/.so) is in your path.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrap.setDebugWrappers(concert_wrap.java:34)
    at ilog.opl.IloOplFactory.setDebugMode(IloOplFactory.java:152)
    at MainNetworkVirtulization.main(MainNetworkVirtulization.java:185)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Native code library failed to load: ensure the appropriate library (opl<VERSION>.dll/.so) is in your path.
    at ilog.concert.IloJNILoader.loadJNI(IloJNILoader.java:79)
    at ilog.concert.cppimpl.concert_wrapJNI.<clinit>(concert_wrapJNI.java:15)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

BY the way, this Java interfaces code runs fine on my other Windows laptop. Does anyone know how to correct the above errors? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your environment variable so that the ILOG libraries can be loaded.

For example, in my `.profile`, I have the following (using cplex, not concert, but you get the idea.):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/cplex125/cplex/bin/x86-64_sles10_4.1
```

you can also run with `-Djava.library.path <path>` and pass that to your VM, but I find the above to be much less of a hassle as you don't have to remember that argument for each invocation.